# How deploy on multiple azure web apps from single TFS build?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, azure-deployment

I have one visual studio .sln in which I have created one web app and one web service app. I want to deploy these apps to respective azure web app and service app.
is there any way to deploy both these apps using single build definition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the new build system in visual studio online?

Comment: I am using visual studio online.

Answer (score 1):

You can have several tasks in one build definition.

For your question, you can add two "Azure Web App Deployment" tasks in your build definition, one to deploy web app and another one to deploy service app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VSTS you can make releases which deploy multiple applications to azure. A release is split in different actions. One of the actions can deploy the first service app and then the service app.

Go to VSTS => release tab or build tab.

In both you can make a Azure Web App Deployment action

Update: How to create a release: http://nkdagility.com/the-high-of-release/

Comment: any reference link ?

Comment: @sam,  Ihave added a reference link.

Answer (score -2):

Create website, download respective config file.
Choose diffrent config file when delpoy to diffrent site.